# Doctrine+symfony yml: fixture value is 0 but loaded in MySQL as NULL

Tags: mysql, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

So I have a schema.yml like this:

```
Product:
  tableName: product
  columns:
    count:
      type: decimal(15,5)
      default: null
      notnull: false
```

And my initial_data.yml like this:

```
Product_724d2a29-8c41-11e2-b0e4-080027706aa2:
    count: '0.00000'
```

However, when I load the data in the DB, count is set to NULL instead of 0.0000

What am I doing wrong? Is there any workaround for this? I guess 0.000 is considered as empty value and then its populated with the default value from the schema.

Comment: may be problem in quotes?

Comment: may be a problem in indentation? as far as I know it must be 2 spaces; in the above code its 4 spaces.